# Moving lvalue reference into member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Assume you're having this simple class:

```
class GenericClass {
public:
    GenericClass(std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>& lref) {
    this->var = std::move(lref);
}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> var;
}
```

How exactly is the ctor handling the "move"?
Is the ownership of the lvalue that the reference points to transferred to the member variable or is the reference *another* lvalue?

Comment: The parameter should really have been an rvalue reference, to make it clear that the constructor moves from it and to require an explicit move from the caller side if lvalue is passed.

Comment: Not that I would criticize but frankly, `this->var = std::move(lref);` as a ctor body is something from a horror movie.

Comment: `std::move` is nothing but a cast.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the effect of the `std::move` can easily be understood with an example:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> data = ... ;

assert(data != nullptr);  //data is not nullptr

GenericClass obj(data); //the resource is transferred

assert(data == nullptr); //data must be nullptr
```

Hope the comments explain what exactly is going on.

However, without the comments, it is not very clear that the resource is transferred from `data` to `obj`, because the design of the constructor isn't good enough. So I'd suggest to make it explicit:

```
GenericClass(std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>&& lref) //note &&
  : var(std::move(lref)) //use mem-initialize-list
{
}
```

Now the client should write this instead:

```
GenericClass obj(std::move(data));
```

Now even without comments, the client-code is understandable.

Comment: Is it necessary to use : var(std::move(lref))? It's already an r-value reference, or at least the argument is.

Comment: @Zebrafish: Yes. `std::move` is necessary there, as `lref` is still an lvalue, though it binds to an rvalue.

Comment: @Zebrafish, Value category is orthogonal to type. It's an lvalue of type rvalue reference to `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`.

Comment: "So I'd suggest to make it explicit" - good idea, that single argument constructor probably *should* be marked `explicit` - not what you were talking about, but still. ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Without knowing the usage of the class, yes marking single-argument constructor `explicit` is a good idea in general.